# What are the steps involved in the execution of an Android program?

Tags: android

I was just reading about the Dalvik Virtual Machine. It got me all confused. I know there is a build tool called gradle in Android Studio. However, these are bits and pieces of information. 
I want to know where they fit in i.e. the steps involved in execution of an Android program.

Thank you

Comment: This is much too broad for a Stack Overflow question. There are [whole books on what is involved in running an Android app](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021094.do).

Comment: you'd do well learning how an operating system works, how it instantiates processes, how compilers, assemblers and linkers work to generate a program, about virtual machines and bytecode, then you'll have an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dalvik Virtual Machine is, like the name says, a virtual machine. This means, that it is actually an emulator for an abstract instruction set architecture. Programs are therefore not compiled into machine code, but into bytecode, which is is the machine code for the virtual machine.
Virtual machines are used because they can run programms unmodifed on any supported underlying processor architecture.
Java, usually uses byte code for the Java virtual machine which is stack based. However on Android, it was decided to use an register based one called Dalvik instead. Also to improve speed, the bytecode isn't interpreted, but  compiled into native machine code during execution (Just in time compilation).

Newer versions of Android (standard from 5.0 onwards) however, improve the runtime performence by compiling the Dalvik byte code into native code not at runtime but during installation of the program.

For further information search for Dalvik, bytecode or Android Runtime.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very broad question, so the answer depends on what specifically you are trying to achieve / which part you're interested in. I'd recommend looking at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) for an overview and references to specific materials.

Comment: Even for a simplistic app like "Hello World" consisting of one single activity?